# Embed table in Adaptive Card with multiple rows from SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, adaptive-cards

I would like to extract data from a subset of SharePoint list rows and display them in a card with an action associated with each row. (See attachment).  The names would come from a list.  The manager then chooses who would be promoted by checking the button. After submitting the response, a series of workflows would trigger based on the button response.

Any suggestions for an approach or, better still, know of any similar examples out there?
Thx

[Example of the card d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zii1f.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've since learned that this can't be done using Adaptive Cards by just using Designer.  Instead, I would have to build up a "stack" of code in a payload externally.  More hassle than it's worth.  Thanks for reaching out, though.